# MVC returns GET action instead of POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've spent nearly an hour trying to figure out why one form in the application does not work. The form works through a pair of GET\POST actions that share the same name. Obviously one is behind a `[HttpPost]` attribute and accepts a model related to the form as an input.

I've made sure that the form has `method="POST"` attribute and that it's actually posted (y monitoring the requests in browser), yet MVC responds with the GET action. I understand that if I don't specifically set it so, an action works for both POST and GET, but I got used to the fact that if I have an action with `[HttpPost]` attribute, it will be preferred over the other one when responding to a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both actions have the same name. It's the most basic thing and thus most overlooked.

I'm ashamed to admit that I've made such a simple mistake. However, since I wasted so much time searching for it, I figured out that it might be worth posting it here, so someone else won't have to waste time like me.

In the end I found the source of the problem when I tried to renamed the POST action to remove any potential ambiguity in action name...